# Whats are some real time data sources?

Tags: real-time, visualization, data-visualization, demo

I'm working on a demo on real-time visualization and I'm trying to think out of the box. Looks like any big data real-time demo is on twitter or traffic data. Are there any other options out there that publish real-time data (for free)?

Thanks

Answer (score 34):

Just some thoughts:

### Environmental Datasets

As stated by the other comment, have a look to [weather](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/), [forecast](https://developer.forecast.io/) (or similar services).

### Space data

[What about data from the Universe?](http://open.nasa.gov/blog/2012/09/19/the-open-api-universe-at-nasa/)

### Flights

Here's some [real time flight tracking data](https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/flightstatus/v2): the evaluation plan is limited but free.

### Social Networks

[Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis), [Facebook RealTime Updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/) (in case you hyave already an app on the social Network), [Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime)

### Energy production

[Various energy production (real-time and quasi real-time) data](https://www.wind-watch.org/documents/real-time-wind-production-various-regions/).
On these ones probably you have to fiddle around the pages to track the sources of the data, sorry.

## Website traffic

[Google Analytics RealTime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) (for your registered websites)

### Money

[Bitcoin transactions](http://blockchain.info/api), [Stock Market API](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs)

## More?

And [here](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/04/17/62-real-time-apis-twitter-thrutu-and-pusher/) and [here](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/01/11/12-json-weather-apis/) an "not-so-updated" list of other Real-Time API services (some free, some others not).

Comment: For free, live streaming data you may also want to check out https://www.satori.com/opendata/channels

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered environmental datasets?

For one, there are near real time (say, hourly or 15m) data on [streamflow and water quality](http://waterdata.usgs.gov/usa/nwis/rt). There's also a wealth of weather data served up via NOAA NCDC and APIs. How about some [bouy data](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/)?

Seeing [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25226/is-there-a-way-to-find-track-my-planes-previous-flight) reminded me that there's lots of flight tracking data out there which could be fun to visualize too.

Answer (score 5):

You can find real-time data sources at www.hooksdata.io. Using a query language you can specify what data you need and then add a webhook URL where you want to receive the data or just pull the data anytime.

API DOCS: https://www.hooksdata.io/docs/api/introduction/

Available data sources with examples:

**RSS**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM RSS('http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/')
```

**TwitterUserTimeline**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM TwitterUserTimeline('Techstars')
```

Output:

```
{ "_entity_type": "tweet", "_id": "tweet_976733289221210112", "contributors": null, "coordinates": null, "created_at": "Thu Mar 22 08:12:17 +0000 2018", "entities": { "hashtags": [ { "indices": [ 121, 132 ], "text": "3Dprinting" } ], "symbols": [], "urls": [], "user_mentions": [ { "id": 117789943, "id_str": "117789943", "indices": [ 3, 19 ], "name": "StanleyBlack&Decker", "screen_name": "StanleyBlkDeckr" }, { "id": 14277276, "id_str": "14277276", "indices": [ 61, 71 ], "name": "techstars", "screen_name": "techstars" } ] }, "favorite_count": 0, "favorited": false, "geo": null, "id": 976733289221210112, "id_str": "976733289221210112", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "is_quote_status": false, "lang": "en", "metadata": { "iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent" }, "place": null, "retweet_count": 7, "retweeted": false, "retweeted_status": { "contributors": null, "coordinates": null, "created_at": "Wed Mar 21 20:37:05 +0000 2018", "entities": { "hashtags": [ { "indices": [ 100, 111 ], "text": "3Dprinting" } ], "symbols": [], "urls": [ { "display_url": "twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026", "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/976558334030442498", "indices": [ 117, 140 ], "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/6GWviWvVd1" } ], "user_mentions": [ { "id": 14277276, "id_str": "14277276", "indices": [ 40, 50 ], "name": "techstars", "screen_name": "techstars" } ] }, "favorite_count": 11, "favorited": false, "geo": null, "id": 976558334030442498, "id_str": "976558334030442498", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "is_quote_status": false, "lang": "en", "metadata": { "iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent" }, "place": null, "possibly_sensitive": false, "retweet_count": 7, "retweeted": false, "source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/percolate.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Percolate<\/a>", "text": "Ahead of the Stanley+Techstars program, @Techstars leaders visited us to see how we've incorporated #3Dprinting and\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/6GWviWvVd1", "truncated": true, "user": { "contributors_enabled": false, "created_at": "Fri Feb 26 16:34:00 +0000 2010", "default_profile": false, "default_profile_image": false, "description": "Official Twitter account for Stanley Black and Decker", "entities": { "description": { "urls": [] }, "url": { "urls": [ { "display_url": "stanleyblackanddecker.com", "expanded_url": "http:\/\/stanleyblackanddecker.com", "indices": [ 0, 22 ], "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/OwfwWAucUP" } ] } }, "favourites_count": 474, "follow_request_sent": false, "followers_count": 5293, "following": false, "friends_count": 170, "geo_enabled": false, "has_extended_profile": false, "id": 117789943, "id_str": "117789943", "is_translation_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "lang": "en", "listed_count": 136, "location": "New Britain", "name": "StanleyBlack&Decker", "notifications": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/84200087\/stanley_twitter_nologos.jpg", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/84200087\/stanley_twitter_nologos.jpg", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/117789943\/1501159100", "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/534427580120571905\/qEDM5_-D_normal.jpeg", "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/534427580120571905\/qEDM5_-D_normal.jpeg", "profile_link_color": "0084B4", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "FFD30D", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "protected": false, "screen_name": "StanleyBlkDeckr", "statuses_count": 1239, "time_zone": null, "translator_type": "none", "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/OwfwWAucUP", "utc_offset": null, "verified": false } }, "source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>", "text": "RT @StanleyBlkDeckr: Ahead of the Stanley+Techstars program, @Techstars leaders visited us to see how we've incorporated #3Dprinting and ad\u2026", "truncated": false, "user": { "contributors_enabled": false, "created_at": "Mon Jul 27 04:06:55 +0000 2015", "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "description": "Humble Star", "entities": { "description": { "urls": [] } }, "favourites_count": 51, "follow_request_sent": false, "followers_count": 26, "following": false, "friends_count": 74, "geo_enabled": false, "has_extended_profile": false, "id": 3296795162, "id_str": "3296795162", "is_translation_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "lang": "en", "listed_count": 0, "location": "", "name": "Munkhi Tse", "notifications": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/3296795162\/1520835673", "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/973081082500235264\/46urpcv1_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/973081082500235264\/46urpcv1_normal.jpg", "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "protected": false, "screen_name": "Munkhitse", "statuses_count": 53, "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "translator_type": "none", "url": null, "utc_offset": -25200, "verified": false } }
```

**TwitterSearch**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM TwitterSearch('Techstars')
```

Output:

```
{ "_entity_type": "tweet", "_id": "tweet_976733289221210112", "contributors": null, "coordinates": null, "created_at": "Thu Mar 22 08:12:17 +0000 2018", "entities": { "hashtags": [ { "indices": [ 121, 132 ], "text": "3Dprinting" } ], "symbols": [], "urls": [], "user_mentions": [ { "id": 117789943, "id_str": "117789943", "indices": [ 3, 19 ], "name": "StanleyBlack&Decker", "screen_name": "StanleyBlkDeckr" }, { "id": 14277276, "id_str": "14277276", "indices": [ 61, 71 ], "name": "techstars", "screen_name": "techstars" } ] }, "favorite_count": 0, "favorited": false, "geo": null, "id": 976733289221210112, "id_str": "976733289221210112", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "is_quote_status": false, "lang": "en", "metadata": { "iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent" }, "place": null, "retweet_count": 7, "retweeted": false, "retweeted_status": { "contributors": null, "coordinates": null, "created_at": "Wed Mar 21 20:37:05 +0000 2018", "entities": { "hashtags": [ { "indices": [ 100, 111 ], "text": "3Dprinting" } ], "symbols": [], "urls": [ { "display_url": "twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026", "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/976558334030442498", "indices": [ 117, 140 ], "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/6GWviWvVd1" } ], "user_mentions": [ { "id": 14277276, "id_str": "14277276", "indices": [ 40, 50 ], "name": "techstars", "screen_name": "techstars" } ] }, "favorite_count": 11, "favorited": false, "geo": null, "id": 976558334030442498, "id_str": "976558334030442498", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "is_quote_status": false, "lang": "en", "metadata": { "iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent" }, "place": null, "possibly_sensitive": false, "retweet_count": 7, "retweeted": false, "source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/percolate.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Percolate<\/a>", "text": "Ahead of the Stanley+Techstars program, @Techstars leaders visited us to see how we've incorporated #3Dprinting and\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/6GWviWvVd1", "truncated": true, "user": { "contributors_enabled": false, "created_at": "Fri Feb 26 16:34:00 +0000 2010", "default_profile": false, "default_profile_image": false, "description": "Official Twitter account for Stanley Black and Decker", "entities": { "description": { "urls": [] }, "url": { "urls": [ { "display_url": "stanleyblackanddecker.com", "expanded_url": "http:\/\/stanleyblackanddecker.com", "indices": [ 0, 22 ], "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/OwfwWAucUP" } ] } }, "favourites_count": 474, "follow_request_sent": false, "followers_count": 5293, "following": false, "friends_count": 170, "geo_enabled": false, "has_extended_profile": false, "id": 117789943, "id_str": "117789943", "is_translation_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "lang": "en", "listed_count": 136, "location": "New Britain", "name": "StanleyBlack&Decker", "notifications": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/84200087\/stanley_twitter_nologos.jpg", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/84200087\/stanley_twitter_nologos.jpg", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/117789943\/1501159100", "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/534427580120571905\/qEDM5_-D_normal.jpeg", "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/534427580120571905\/qEDM5_-D_normal.jpeg", "profile_link_color": "0084B4", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "FFD30D", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "protected": false, "screen_name": "StanleyBlkDeckr", "statuses_count": 1239, "time_zone": null, "translator_type": "none", "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/OwfwWAucUP", "utc_offset": null, "verified": false } }, "source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>", "text": "RT @StanleyBlkDeckr: Ahead of the Stanley+Techstars program, @Techstars leaders visited us to see how we've incorporated #3Dprinting and ad\u2026", "truncated": false, "user": { "contributors_enabled": false, "created_at": "Mon Jul 27 04:06:55 +0000 2015", "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "description": "Humble Star", "entities": { "description": { "urls": [] } }, "favourites_count": 51, "follow_request_sent": false, "followers_count": 26, "following": false, "friends_count": 74, "geo_enabled": false, "has_extended_profile": false, "id": 3296795162, "id_str": "3296795162", "is_translation_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "lang": "en", "listed_count": 0, "location": "", "name": "Munkhi Tse", "notifications": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/3296795162\/1520835673", "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/973081082500235264\/46urpcv1_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/973081082500235264\/46urpcv1_normal.jpg", "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "protected": false, "screen_name": "Munkhitse", "statuses_count": 53, "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "translator_type": "none", "url": null, "utc_offset": -25200, "verified": false } }
```

**NFLGames**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM NFLGames
WHERE status = 'FUTURE' and
away_team.team_name = 'New England Patriots' OR
home_team.team_name = 'New England Patriots' AND
start_datetime.countdown = 3600
```

**SoccerGames**:
Input:

```
SELECT * FROM SoccerGames
WHERE away_team.team_name = 'Real Madrid'
OR home_team.team_name = 'Real Madrid'
AND start_datetime.countdown = 3600
```

Output:

```
{
"matches_count": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "_entity_type": "SoccerGame",
        "_id": "SoccerGame_490555",
        "away_score": null,
        "away_team": {
            "_entity_type": "SoccerTeam",
            "_id": "SoccerTeam_86",
            "espn_id": 86,
            "id": "SoccerTeam_86",
            "logo_url": "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/soccer/500/86.png&h=500",
            "team_name": "Real Madrid"
        },
        "competition": "Spanish Primera División",
        "game_id": "490555",
        "home_score": null,
        "home_team": {
            "_entity_type": "SoccerTeam",
            "_id": null,
            "team_name": "Leganes"
        },
        "link": "http://m.espn.go.com/soccer/gamecast?gameId=490555&lang=EN&wjb=",
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": 86970,
            "datetime": "2018-02-21T17:45:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519235100
        },
        "status": "FUTURE",
        "timestamp": 1519235100
    }
]
```

}

**EpisodesByTVShow**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM
EpisodesByTVShow(name = 'Game of Thrones')
WHERE start_datetime.countdown = 3600
```

Output:

```
{
        "_entity_type": "Episode",
        "_id": "Episode_4961",
        "image": {
            "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_landscape/1/2681.jpg",
            "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/1/2681.jpg"
        },
        "link": "http://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/4961/game-of-thrones-1x10-fire-and-blood",
        "number": 10,
        "runtime": 60,
        "season": 1,
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": -210591933,
            "datetime": "2011-06-20T01:00:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1308531600
        },
        "summary": "Daenerys must realize her destiny. Jaime finds himself in an unfamiliar predicament.",
        "title": "Fire and Blood",
        "tvmaze_episode_id": 4961,
        "tvshow": {
            "_entity_type": "TVShow",
            "_id": "TVShow_82",
            "externals": {
                "imdb": "tt0944947",
                "thetvdb": 121361,
                "tvrage": 24493
            },
            "genres": [
                "Drama",
                "Adventure",
                "Fantasy"
            ],
            "id": "TVShow_82",
            "image": {
                "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/143/359013.jpg",
                "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/143/359013.jpg"
            },
            "language": "English",
            "name": "Game of Thrones",
            "network": {
                "country": {
                    "code": "US",
                    "name": "United States",
                    "timezone": "America/New_York"
                },
                "id": 8,
                "name": "HBO"
            },
            "officialSite": "http://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones",
            "premiered": "2011-04-17",
            "rating": {
                "average": 9.3
            },
            "runtime": 60,
            "schedule": {
                "days": [
                    "Sunday"
                ],
                "time": "21:00"
            },
            "status": "Running",
            "summary": "<p>Based on the bestselling book series <i>A Song of Ice and Fire</i> by George R.R. Martin, this sprawling new HBO drama is set in a world where summers span decades and winters can last a lifetime. From the scheming south and the savage eastern lands, to the frozen north and ancient Wall that protects the realm from the mysterious darkness beyond, the powerful families of the Seven Kingdoms are locked in a battle for the Iron Throne. This is a story of duplicity and treachery, nobility and honor, conquest and triumph. In the <b>Game of Thrones</b>, you either win or you die.</p>",
            "tvmaze_id": 82,
            "type": "Scripted",
            "updated": 1517168016,
            "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/82/game-of-thrones",
            "webChannel": {
                "country": {
                    "code": "US",
                    "name": "United States",
                    "timezone": "America/New_York"
                },
                "id": 22,
                "name": "HBO Go"
            },
            "weight": 99
        }
    }
```

**WeatherByCity**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM WeatherByCity
(name = 'San Francisco'
AND country.name = 'United States'
AND subdivision.type = 'State'
AND subdivision.name = 'California')
WHERE weather_conditions.main = 'Rain'
AND start_datetime.countdown = 86400
```

Output:

```
{
        "_entity_type": "WeatherStatus",
        "_id": "WeatherStatus_Geoname_5391959-1519178400",
        "city": {
            "_entity_type": "City",
            "_id": "Geoname_5391959",
            "admin1_code": "CA",
            "admin2_code": "075",
            "admin3_code": null,
            "admin4_code": null,
            "alternative_names": [
                "Franciscopolis",
                "Frisco",
                "Gorad San-Francyska",
                "Kapalakiko",
                "Khiu-kim-san",
                "Khiu-kîm-sân",
                "Lungsod ng San Francisco",
                "New Albion",
                "SF",
                "SFO",
                "San Francisco",
                "San Franciscu",
                "San Francisko",
                "San Fransisco",
                "San Fransiskas",
                "San Fransisko",
                "San Frantzisko",
                "San Phransisko",
                "San-Francisko",
                "San-Fransisko",
                "Sanfrancisko",
                "Sao Francisco",
                "São Francisco",
                "Yerba Buena",
                "can pirancisko",
                "jiu jin shan",
                "saenpeulan",
                "saenpeulansiseuko",
                "saina pharansisako",
                "saina phransisko",
                "san f ran si s ko",
                "san fan shi",
                "san fransskw",
                "san fransyskw",
                "san fransyskۆ",
                "san phransisko",
                "sana phransisako ka'unti",
                "sana phransisko",
                "sanfuranshisuko",
                "sena phransisko",
                "sn prnsysqw",
                "syana phransisko",
                "Σαν Φρανσίσκο",
                "Горад Сан-Францыска",
                "Сан Франсиско",
                "Сан Франциско",
                "Сан-Франциско",
                "Сан-Франціско",
                "Սան Ֆրանցիսկո",
                "סאן פראנציסקא",
                "סן פרנסיסקו",
                "سان فرانسسکو",
                "سان فرانسيسكو",
                "سان فرانسیسکو",
                "سان فرانسیسکۆ",
                "सॅन फ्रान्सिस्को",
                "सैन फ्रांसिस्को",
                "स्यान फ्रान्सिस्को",
                "সান ফ্রান্সিসকো কাউন্টি",
                "সান ফ্রান্সিস্কো",
                "ਸੈਨ ਫਰਾਂਸਿਸਕੋ",
                "சான் பிரான்சிஸ்கோ",
                "శాన్ ఫ్రాన్సిస్కో",
                "സാൻ ഫ്രാൻസിസ്കോ",
                "සැන් ෆ්\u200dරැන්සිස්කෝ",
                "ซานฟรานซิสโก",
                "སན་ཧྥུ་རན་སིས་ཁོ",
                "ဆန်ဖရန်စစ္စကိုမြို့",
                "სან-ფრანცისკო",
                "サンフランシスコ",
                "三藩市",
                "旧金山",
                "舊金山",
                "샌프란",
                "샌프란시스코"
            ],
            "ascii_name": "San Francisco",
            "coordinates": "37.77493,-122.41942",
            "country": {
                "country_code_2": "US",
                "country_code_3": "USA",
                "country_numeric_code": "840",
                "name": "United States",
                "official_name": "United States of America"
            },
            "dem": "28",
            "elevation": 16,
            "feature_class": "P",
            "feature_code": "PPLA2",
            "geonameid": "5391959",
            "id": "Geoname_5391959",
            "modification_date": "2017-06-15",
            "name": "San Francisco",
            "population": 864816,
            "subdivision": {
                "country_code_2": "US",
                "name": "California",
                "subdivision_code": "US-CA",
                "type": "State"
            },
            "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "features": {
            "clouds_percent": 44,
            "humidity_percent": 83,
            "pressure": {
                "hPa": 1027.12,
                "inHg": 30.33,
                "mmHg": 770.4
            },
            "rain": {
                "inch_hour": 0,
                "mm_hour": 0
            },
            "snow": {
                "inch_hour": 0,
                "mm_hour": 0
            },
            "temperature": {
                "celsius": 8.36,
                "fahrenheit": 32
            },
            "wind_direction_degrees": 297.002,
            "wind_speed": {
                "meters_per_second": 3.42,
                "miles_per_hour": 7.65
            }
        },
        "is_current": false,
        "measure_time": {
            "countdown": 42931,
            "datetime": "2018-02-21T03:00:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519182000
        },
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": 39331,
            "datetime": "2018-02-21T02:00:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519178400
        },
        "weather_conditions": [
            {
                "description": "scattered clouds",
                "icon": "03n",
                "icon_url": "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/03n",
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**NBAGames**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM NBAGames
WHERE status='FUTURE'
AND (away_team.team_name='Charlotte Hornets'
OR home_team.team_name='Charlotte Hornets')
AND start_datetime.countdown = 3600
```

Output:

```
{
"matches_count": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "_entity_type": "NBAGame",
        "_id": "NBAGame_400975613",
        "away_score": null,
        "away_team": {
            "_entity_type": "NBATeam",
            "_id": "NBATeam_CHA",
            "acronym": "CHA",
            "division": "Southeast",
            "id": "NBATeam_CHA",
            "team_name": "Charlotte Hornets"
        },
        "game_id": "400975613",
        "home_team": {
            "_entity_type": "NBATeam",
            "_id": null,
            "acronym": null
        },
        "link": "http://espn.go.com/nba/game?gameId=400975613",
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": 137435,
            "datetime": "2018-02-23T00:00:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519344000
        },
        "status": "FUTURE"
    }
]
```

}

**MLBGames**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM MLBGames
WHERE status = 'FUTURE'
AND (away_team.team_name = 'Toronto Blue Jays'
OR home_team.team_name = 'Toronto Blue Jays')
AND start_datetime.countdown = 3600
```

Output:

```
{
"matches_count": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "_entity_type": "MLBGame",
        "_id": "MLBGame_400962533",
        "away_score": null,
        "away_team": {
            "_entity_type": "MLBTeam",
            "_id": "MLBTeam_TOR",
            "acronym": "TOR",
            "division": "AL East",
            "id": "MLBTeam_TOR",
            "team_name": "Toronto Blue Jays"
        },
        "game_id": "400962533",
        "home_team": {
            "_entity_type": "MLBTeam",
            "_id": null,
            "acronym": null
        },
        "link": "http://espn.go.com/nhl/gamecast?gameId=400962533",
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": 135524,
            "datetime": "2018-02-23T00:00:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519344000
        },
        "status": "FUTURE"
    }
]
```

}

**NHLGames**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM NHLGames
WHERE status='FUTURE'
AND (away_team.team_name='New Jersey Devils'
OR home_team.team_name='New Jersey Devils')
AND start_datetime.countdown = 3600
```

Output:

```
{
"matches_count": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "_entity_type": "NHLGame",
        "_id": "NHLGame_400962534",
        "away_score": null,
        "away_team": {
            "_entity_type": "NHLTeam",
            "_id": "NHLTeam_NJ",
            "acronym": "NJ",
            "division": "Metropolitan Division",
            "id": "NHLTeam_NJ",
            "team_name": "New Jersey Devils"
        },
        "game_id": "400962534",
        "home_team": {
            "_entity_type": "NHLTeam",
            "_id": null,
            "acronym": null
        },
        "link": "http://espn.go.com/nhl/gamecast?gameId=400962534",
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": 134517,
            "datetime": "2018-02-23T00:00:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519344000
        },
        "status": "FUTURE"
    }
]
```

}

**CryptoTickers**:

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM CryptoTickers
WHERE market_cap_usd >= 18000000000
```

**StockTickers**:

```
SELECT * FROM StockTickers('AAPL')
WHERE close > 170
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm been working with [Ably Hub](https://www.ably.io/hub/) - it is a marketplace for open streaming data sources, which are either paid or free to use under different licenses.

Full disclosure: I'm a Developer Advocate for Ably but I think the resources from this marketplace might certainly help you with some cool data viz.

If you are interested in checking out an example - I built a [live bitcoin price chart](https://www.ably.io/tutorials/live-bitcoin-pricing#title) using one of the sources from the Ably Hub and KendoUI.

[image]

Comment: I've tried the Ably Hub after reading this answer and **I would recommend against it**. It is badly documented and confusing to use. I failed to replicate some of the basic tutorials from their website. Their Python support library is unusable. The idea behind it is cool but *Sounds good, doesn't work.*